# Node & GraphQL Auth

Tags: node.js, graphql

What is the recommended method of handling user authentication and token creation using Node/Graphql?  I see a lot of tutorials out there that use a REST endpoint to authorize the user and generate the token.

While I'm new to the GraphQL scene, I don't see why you wouldn't use GraphQL for this.

For example, why not have a query like this which gets sent to a resolver that checks the user/pass and generates a token? :

```
mutation {
  loginUser (
    username: "YOURUSERNAME", 
    password:"YOURPASSWORD"
  ) 
  {
    token
  }
}
```

Is there a specific reason that the tutorials I've gone through haven't done it this way?  Is there some sort of flaw in this method that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Just a few ideas why auth might not be popular in Roanoke yet. It works if you’re just using a token in the response but there are scenarios where the auth might be outside the graphql spec. Example, setting cookies. Also, generally you have legacy authentication systems that your app might use directly. Example, login via google with a client side flow.

Answer (score 0):

The official docs explain the reasoning a bit: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/

Reading between the lines a bit, it seems there isn't any official recommendation to *not* do this, but existing tools expect headers to be used and classic endpoints so this fits better.

If you start talking about OAUTH you're going to have to implement classic URLs anyways as well to complete that dance.

Comment: Thanks for that url Jeff.  Cleared some stuff up for me :)